# Error in sticky navigation and coverflow plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this page where there should be a sticky navigation attached to it. On the page, there is a coverflow plugin that I got from [dynamicdrive.com](http://www.dynamicdrive,com)

coverflow plugin is like an image slider. it looks like this:
[image]

It scrolls from left to right using the scroll wheel or you could click an image to focus on it. It was working until I added the code needed for the sticky navigation. which is this exactly:

```
<!--sticky menu-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<!--ends here-->
```

If you comment out this part of the code, the coverflow plugin works but the sticky navigation does not, also if it is not marked as a comment, the sticky navigation works but the coverflow plugin gets stuck and won't move or do the animation.

I thought the z-index was causing this but it doesn't do anything. And I am sure both works but don't want to work hand in hand. Is there a way to fix this?

I am unable to add all the code here even in jsfiddle because there is more than 1 css and js assigned to it. and I believe that you could only assign one to jsfiddle

I hope someone could help me out here

i tried my best to sum it up at jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/misaki03/40fq496r/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For image slider, use [wow slider](http://wowslider.com/). It is the most preferred over others because of no compatibility issues along with other features and can work in html5. It also provides more features and animations. I prefer this one. Only downside of wow slider is that there  is a watermark on slider. But you can remove that too from youtube. Search for "Wow Slider Watermark Remove".

-Peace :)

Comment: how do I attach that to my site?

Comment: well it does seem like just compatibility. this works well for me and solved my problem. at the same time very useful since i could use this in my other sites as well.